# Xercesc DOMDocument - Compare two XML documents

Tags: c++, xml, xerces, xerces-c

I am using xercesc (C++) library for processing XML documents with xercesc::XercesDOMParser class.
What is the simplest way to compare two XML documents?
Say, I use:

```
XercesDOMParser parser1;
parser1.parse("1.xml");
DOMDocument* doc1 = parser1.getDocument();

XercesDOMParser parser2;
parser2.parse("2.xml");
DOMDocument* doc2 = parser2.getDocument();
```

How can I know that doc1 and doc2 are identical from the xml point of view (i.e. they can have different spaces/end-of-lines/indentation, but represent same XML content)?

Comment: If there isn't an explicit way to do so, maybe you can try to serialize the data using Xercesc's `DOMLSSerializer` and write out the XML in strings and compare? Or alternatively use Xercesc's `DOMTreeWalker` to traverse the DOM tree, store your results, then compare.

Comment: If there's no an interface to compare two documents, then I would assume the following solution would work: print each document into a string and compare those strings. But does xerces-c have a canonical-form printing into string?

Comment: The `DOMLSSerializer` has a `writeToString()` method; try that one.

Comment: This totally depends on what you mean by _"compare two XML documents"_. If all you want to know is if they're identical, then serialization followed by string compare is all you need.  If you want a detailed "diff", that's a much more complex problem, needing further definition to specify what "equal" and "different" mean for your particular data set.  This question can't really be answered in its current form, which is why it hasn't been answered in 8 years.

Comment: 8 years? You could have written your own and added it to Xerces. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can **serialize** both documents to strings and then compare the strings.

This method ensures that the content of the XML documents is compared regardless of formatting differences like **spaces**, **EOLs**, or **indentation**.

Here's a simple code to achieve it:

```
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMImplementation.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMWriter.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/LocalFileFormatTarget.hpp>

bool compareXMLDocuments(DOMDocument* doc1, DOMDocument* doc2)
{
    XMLCh tempStr[100];
    XMLString::transcode("LS", tempStr, 99);
    DOMImplementation* impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(tempStr);
    DOMWriter* writer = static_cast<DOMImplementationLS*>(impl)->createDOMWriter();
    XMLCh* xml1 = writer->writeToString(doc1);
    XMLCh* xml2 = writer->writeToString(doc2);
    bool isEqual = XMLString::equals(xml1, xml2);
    XMLString::release(&xml1);
    XMLString::release(&xml2);
    writer->release();
    return isEqual;
}
```